# Google Analytics Event Tracking - How to track an auto-popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

We have a popup that appears after a certain number of pageviews on our site and I would like to track this as an event.

I currently have

```
<script>
  ga('send', {
 'hitType': 'pageview',
 'page': '/signupPopup'
});
 </script>
```

In my popup but I'm having trouble determining if this is the correct format.  The main GA script is located at the footer of the entire site (on every page), but this is a jquery pop up div with this script included.  Do I need to include anything else to track a simple page hit/view?

Comment: What kind of ga code you've got? If it's the new universal check out this for instructions  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide

Comment: Upgrated to Universal last week.  Every example I find is for when someone clicks on something as opposed to simply recording an event when the pop up is displayed.  I'm looking for a simple line of script to add to the pop up to record the event, if this is possible.

Comment: This should work:
ga('send', 'pageview', '/popup');

Comment: Thanks Lior - just stick that anywhere on the pop up page itself?

Comment: Yep or on in the open popup function if it's not in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to post the entire tracking code inside the popup (I am using an iframe, as it turns out) then used

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'domain.com');
ga('send', 'event', 'popup', 'popup');
```